# Can a virus infect windows 10 bootable media?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, windows-10, antimalware

I created a bootable windows 10 usb from my friend's computer. I used the official tool from microsoft. I was dumb enough to not check my friend's computer beforehand (turns out he had Utorrent Web installed, a known PUPbundler, and maybe some other malicious programs)

I plugged in the drive into my PC and installed windows 10. Everything seems to be in order. I ran a malwarebytes scan and scanned the contents of the bootable media. All of it came up clean.

I am still paranoid. Is it possible/likely that the viruses in my friend's pc tampered with the bootable usb and made its way to my pc and "hidden" themselves in such a way that they are undetectable by malwarebytes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible, but unlikely.

Comment: Secure boot is suppose to block boot viruses.  Will the USB boot with secure boot on?  If it will, it's fine.  If it won't, it doesn't mean it is infected however.  Same for your installed system -- if it boots with secure boot on, at least you know you don't have a boot virus.